# Aftermarket Glass Run Rubber (for '94 Nissan D21 Truck)

Tags: maintenance, nissan, parts, paint

I am searching for the Glass Run Rubber for a 1994 D21 Nissan Truck (what the window rolls up into on the outside of the vehicle door).

My local dealership said the factory part numbers are [80335N (RH)](http://www.courtesyparts.com/-p-221553.html) and [80336N (LH)](http://www.courtesyparts.com/-p-221555.html), but the dealership price is about $140 for each side.

$280 + Shipping ($300) seems extravagant for a 1994 vehicle.

Does anyone know where I could find wholesale or equivalent aftermarket items?

[image: 803 Front Door Window & Regulator]

Comment: The shipping is ridiculous, but the parts prices seem about right...  I paid around $1000 to get new door/t-top seals for my 1991 Toyota...

Comment: They said they don't stock this, so it has to be special ordered from Japan. Most parts I can search on eBay using the part numbers and find some New Old Stock on someone's shelf for next to nothing. These parts I'm having problems with, though.

Answer (score 1):

Door rubber has been expensive forever.  Try an auto wreckers, but be aware many will not stock parts for cars over ten years old.

Comment: +1 I can understand why! I just had this truck repainted, and my stock  `glass run rubbers` practically tore up when they pulled them off. I just really hate the idea that I'll be buying these parts at that new price. I'll give this question some time before I mark an answer.